# Change an input value when clicking on an area

Tags: php, html, image, input, areas

I have an image in HTML/PHP with different areas. When I click on one of the areas I want my input field above to change. How do I do that? Trying to use a normal $variable but I dont get that to work either.

I am very new to HTML.

Thanks in advance!

```
<input type="text" name="position" size="10" value="">

<img style="margin: 50px 500px" src="pic.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt=":("
usemap="#cabmap" />

<map name="cabmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="20,0,82,126" alt="Sun" *something here mby?* />



<html>
<head>
<title>Pos</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="process.php">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>ChosePos</strong></Legend>

<td style="padding-left: 40px"><b>Position</b></td>
<input id="position" type="text" name="position" size="10" value="Hellope"</input>
<br />
<img src="pic.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt="Position map" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="CA1" onclick="javascript:simply();" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function simply(){
    var box = document.getElementById("position");
    box.value="Hello";
  </script>

  </map>


</fieldset>

<input style="pading-top: 20px" type="submit" value="Send report" />



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now have I've gotten this far but nothin happens when i click on the area...

I have no idea whats wrong. Plz help me.

Comment: You'll need to use jQuery to achieve it. Google will help you out

Comment: show some code for reference...

Comment: @asprin jQuery is *not* necessary, some pure vanilla javascript will be enough for this purpose.

Comment: @DanLee Agree. But jQuery makes it so much simpler

Comment: @asprin, the fact jquery makes it simpler is not in question, but the statement "you'll need to use jquery" is simply incorrect.

Comment: @freefaller Oh..didn't look it from that angle. I should have used 'You can' instead of 'You will'

Comment: Your `<input id="position">` is badly formatted, because there is no closing `>` at the end. Either add the `>` or instead remove the `</input>` and turn it into a self-closing tag with `/>` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** - if this is still marked as the "correct" answer...

I have tried explaining to the OP that my answer was based on the errors they had introduced when implementing the changes suggested by user1474090.  And as a result, they should mark the answer from user1474090 as the "correct" one... and **not** this one.

---

**Original Answer**

In response to your **updated question**, you have a couple of syntax errors.

Firstly, your `<input id="position"` is badly formatted, so change...

```
<input id="position" type="text" name="position" size="10" value="Hellope"</input>
```

Into **one** of the following two lines...

```
<input id="position" type="text" name="position" size="10" value="Hellope"></input>
<input id="position" type="text" name="position" size="10" value="Hellope"/>
```

Secondly, your JavaScript function doesn't have a close brace `}`, so change...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function simply(){
  var box = document.getElementById("position");
  box.value="Hello";
</script>
```

To...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function simply(){
    var box = document.getElementById("position");
    box.value="Hello";
  }
</script>
```

I would also suggest that you move the `<script>` block into the `<head>` section of your page, rather than being part of the `<body>`.  This is not vital for it to work, but it is the preferred way of having scripts in your page.

And I can thoroughly recommend [FireBug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com) or use the developer components in Chrome and IE8/9 (F12 for both).  These would very quickly allow you find issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this using the external JavaScript library **jQuery**:

```
<map name="cabmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="20,0,82,126" alt="Sun" onclick="$('#position').val('Hello')"/>
```

Or you can do this with plain **JavaScript:**

```
<map name="cabmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="20,0,82,126" alt="Sun" onclick="javascript:simply();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function simply(){
 var box = document.getElementById("position");
 box.value="Hello"; 
}    
</script>
```

Also remember to add a id attribute to your text box.

Comment: You can also use pure JavaScript instead of jQuery, although this may make the code a bit lengthier. You can refer to an `input` element by its `name` attribute, too, though an `id` attribute is more handy (especially if there are several elements with the same `name`).

Comment: Why is it a # before position? Should it work after I use the code above and after I put name="position" in the input/text box or do I need to do something with JQuery too? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Okey, javascript looks nice. Since I'm pretty good at Java. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm, I've been struggling for a while now but nothing i try seems to work. I made the javascript above and all other stuff but when I click on the area nothing happens.

Comment: @user1516844, see my answer for why I think your changes are not working. The answer given here by user1474090 is answering your original question, mine is just pointing out syntax errors, please remember this if/when you decide to mark a question as accepted (i.e. it should be this answer, **not** mine)

Comment: @user1474090 - sorry, I've tried to explain to the OP that your answer should be the "accepted" answer (as there can only be a single "accepted" one)